# Pin commands to bash history?

Tags: linux, bash

In the bash shell I use `ctrl-r` or `history | grep ...` to find old commands. Sometimes they are not found. I guess mainly because of the order I close terminal windows or because they are too old. I'm aware of HISTSIZE and HISTIGNORE.

Is there some way of "pinning" specific commands, perhaps defined by a regexp, to `~/.bash_history`? To make them stay there "forever". (I'm considering making a perl cronjob to manipulate ~/.bash_history, but if I don't have to...).

Comment: In recent versions of Bash, you can instead set your command history size to unlimited by setting `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` to negative values. Furthermore, with a little work, you can get all  your sessions write to a combined history, see for example [this Q&A on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows).

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that, by default, lines starting with a space are not recorded in the history. If you know, you know, if you don't it is confusing. You can set up a separate history window for each terminal session with a bit of scripting work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the SO rules. This question is specifically about a specific software, bash, and a specific part of bash at that. How is this "general software". If this question is not a specific question about specific software, what is?

Comment: Here's how I "pin" commands in `bash`: I add a bash comment on the end of the line with a keyword in it, and then search for that later. You could add a suffix of `#pinned` and then search backwards in history for "pinned" to find your pinned commands.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't, but I think what you need are aliases. Love a command? Make an alias.

```
alias pinthis="crazy -command | I -wont remember.later"
```

Comment: I guess I could add even more aliases and "helper scripts" than I already have. But thats not always easy, think of `find` variants or `perl` oneliners where a pletora of different options are used in different situations. What would be nice, I think, was if the bash history could have some sort of weighting system it used to decide which commands to forget first. In addition to the FIFO system now. (First in first out). Where you could say that `find` commands forexample are more important to remember than `man` or that longer commands are more important than shorter.

Comment: That sounds like a cool idea, albeit hard to develop using the UNIX philosophy of doing one thing and one thing right. But you should build it :)

Comment: Bash's defaults we're chosen in the early 90s for machines with 8MB RAM and 100MB disks. Just set it up to not forget anything ever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of those "specific commands" then you can use alias in bashrc which is much better and simpler way.

Like add following entry to your ~/.bashrc

```
alias <aliasname>='<command>'
```

Now each time you want to use your command you can use the alias instead.

For example i use git commit origin/master a lot so following entry exists in my ~/.bashrc

```
alias gitcm='git commit origin/master'
```

This allows me to only type `gitcm` to call the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create an alias, you may want to use *histexpand* option for this purpose.

Following is an example for my history file;

```
  900  history 3
  901  ls -l
  902  cd /var/log/
  903  ls -l
  904  history 5
```

If *histexpand* option is enabled, -it is enabled default-, when you type `!901` it will automaticly run `ls -l` from your history file.